# Update with native query Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to execute a native query that will set field in table to NULL here is my code :

```
@Modifying(flushAutomatically = true, clearAutomatically = true)
@Query(value = "UPDATE orders SET my_field = NULL", nativeQuery = true)
void deleteFields();
```

And in my service I have this method :

```
@Override
public Boolean clearField() throws Exception {
    this.orderRepository.deleteFields();
    return true;
}
```

When I excute it I get this exception :

```
18-05-2018 09:51:37.057 [http-nio-8083-exec-1] WARN  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.logException - Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'flush' call; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'flush' call
```

When I add the the annotation @Transaction (org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional) I don't get the exception but nothing happens, the field is not updated in the Database

Comment: IMO you have a problem in configuring the Spring. Any other queries work ?

Comment: Yes I have but they're only SELECT queries not UPDATE

Comment: UPDATE orders SET my_field = NULL where id in (select id from orders)

Comment: Maybe the problem is in @Modifying(flushAutomatically = true, clearAutomatically = true), remove flushAutomatically = true and annotate your method with @Transactional, could work fine